# gstack.c:14:3: error: unknown type name 'gqdata'

Tags: c

i am trying to implement a generic stack in C. I just wrote this raw piece of code and I am getting a big number of errors and warnings. However, one thing I do no understand is the following error (and other similar ones):

```
In file included from gstack.c:3:
./gstack.h:7:1: error: unknown type name 'gqueue'
gqueue create_queue();
^
./gstack.h:8:13: error: unknown type name 'gqueue'
int enqueue(gqueue *Q, gqdata *D);
            ^
./gstack.h:8:24: error: unknown type name 'gqdata'
int enqueue(gqueue *Q, gqdata *D);
```

gstack.h:

```
#ifndef _GSTACK_H_
#define _GSTACK_H_

void *gqueue;
void *gqdata;

gqueue create_queue();
int enqueue(gqueue *Q, gqdata *D);
int dequeue(gqueue *Q);
void to_string(gqueue *q);

#endif
```

gstack.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "gstack.h"

void *gqueue;
void *gqdata;

typedef struct queue {
  Node *tos;
} Queue;

typedef struct node {
  Node *next;
  gqdata data;
} Node;

gqueue create_queue(){
  Queue queue = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
  if (queue != NULL) {
    queue->tos = NULL;
  }
  return queue;
}
int enqueue(gqueue *Q, gqdata *D) {
  Queue queue = (Queue *) Q;
  Node node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  if (node != NULL) {
    node->next = queue->tos;
    node->data = D;
    Q->tos = node;
    return 1;
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
int dequeue(gqueue *Q) {
  Queue *queue = (Queue *) Q;
  if (queue == NULL || queue->tos == NULL) return 0;
  queue->tos = queue->tos->next;
  return 1;
}

void to_string(gqueue *Q) {
  Queue *queue = (Queue *) Q;
  if (queue == NULL || queue->tos == NULL) return 0;
  queue->tos = queue->tos->next;
  return 1;
}

void to_string(gqueue *Q) {
  Queue *queue = (Queue *) Q;
  Node *cursor = Queue->tos;
  while(cursor != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n");
    cursor = cursor->next;
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The compiler error message is quite obvious, isn't it? It says that `gqueue` is not a type. Make it a type...

Comment: Obviously, i don't know how - i'm a newbie in C

Answer (score 0):

`void *gqueue; void *gqdata;` declares both `gqueue` and `gqdata` as *variables* that are pointers to `void`; thus, you can't use them as names of types.  What exactly do you want `gqueue` and `gqdata` to be?

Answer (score 0):

Move these lines from 'gstack.c' to 'gstack.h'

```
 typedef struct queue {
   Node *tos;
 } Queue;

 typedef struct node {
   Node *next;
   gqdata data;
 } Node;
```

However, in 'gstack.h', change to this:

```
 typedef struct node {
   struct node *next;
   gqdata data;
 } Node;

 typedef struct queue {
   Node *tos;
 } Queue;
```

---

Eliminate these lines from gstack.h:

```
void *gqueue;
void *gqdata;
```

---

Then, in both gstack.h and gstack.c replace all references to `gqueue` with 'Queue'

---

Then add the following line  above the structure typedefs in gstack.h:

```
typedef void * gqdata;
```